# Is "is accommodated in" correct?

Tags: verbs

One dictionary defines "accommodate" as follows:
[To have enough space for: a parking lot big enough to accommodate buses.](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=accommodate)

So, I think this word means capability not state/condition.  For example, can this example be rewritten as follows?

> Some buses are accommodated in the parking lot.

That is, I would like to know whether "accommodate" can be used to mean that something has something inside it.

Comment: From the full OED **accommodate** - *To equip, prepare, make provision for, allow; (hence) to assist, provide comfort or convenience to.* Leading to the very specific sense *To provide lodging for (a person), esp. as a guest; to house; (also) to receive as an inmate.* That's not at all the same as saying that *"accommodate" can be used to mean that something has something inside it* - it just so happens that in *some* contexts, if a "place" "**provides** [hospitality]" to someone, that implies the recipient being ***inside*** the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of **accommodate** is correct. For reference the [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accommodate) dictionary defines as:

> 1. to provide with something desired, needed, or suited
> 2. to make room for
> 3. to hold without crowding or inconvenience

**accommodated** is just the past tense of **accommodate**, so for example:

- Today: Can you **accommodate** me in your hotel?
- Tomorrow: They **accommodated** me the the hotel.

As for your example, though most people would understand your meaning, it would be more correct to say:

> Some buses have been accommodated in the parking lot.

or

> Some buses are been accommodated in the parking lot.